# create entity from database wizard jpa 2.1 @ManyToMany, fix list not needed

Tags: java, jpa-2.1

i have some join tables like this [multimedia_feature](http://postimg.org/image/al2hdae8b/).

The wizard will create in Multimedia class a List attribute:

```
...
@JoinTable(name = "multimedia_feature", joinColumns = {
   @JoinColumn(name = "feature_oid", referencedColumnName = "oid")}, inverseJoinColumns = {
   @JoinColumn(name = "multimedia_oid", referencedColumnName = "oid")})
@ManyToMany
private List<Feature> featureList;
...
```

since i just need a ManyToOne relationship (one feature can have many multimedia file), i flagged multimedia_oid as UNIQUE.
After this the wizard creates other 2 tables (i think redoundant)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "multimedia_feature")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "MultimediaFeature.findAll", query = "SELECT m FROM MultimediaFeature m"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "MultimediaFeature.findByMultimediaOid", query = "SELECT m FROM MultimediaFeature m WHERE m.multimediaFeaturePK.multimediaOid = :multimediaOid"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "MultimediaFeature.findByFeatureOid", query = "SELECT m FROM MultimediaFeature m WHERE m.multimediaFeaturePK.featureOid = :featureOid")})
public class MultimediaFeature implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @EmbeddedId
    protected MultimediaFeaturePK multimediaFeaturePK;
    @JoinColumn(name = "multimedia_oid", referencedColumnName = "oid", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @OneToOne(optional = false)
    private Multimedia multimedia;
    @JoinColumn(name = "feature_oid", referencedColumnName = "oid", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Feature feature;
...
...
```

and

```
@Embeddable
public class MultimediaFeaturePK implements Serializable {

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "multimedia_oid")
    private int multimediaOid;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "feature_oid")
    private int featureOid;
    ...
    ...
```

finally it added an attribute in Multimedia class:

```
....
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "multimedia")
    private MultimediaFeature multimediaFeature;
....
```

since I have really many join classes, I would avoid creating all of these classes.
Can i manually create the attributes, such as:

```
@JoinTable(name = "multimedia_feature",
           @JoinColumn(name"feature_oid", referencedColumnName = "oid")
)
    @OneToOne(optional = false)
    private Feature feature;
```

or this precludes the correct persistence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks the feature attribute in Multimedia class should be a @ManyToOne relationship. 
By default, join tables are created for the mapping of many-to-many relationships and unidirectional one-to-many relationships.
If you want to avoid the join class, I think you can map the multimedia attribute in Feature class by using the @JoinTable like that:

```
@OneToMany
@JoinTable(name = "multimedia_feature",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "feature_oid"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "multimedia_oid") )
private List<Multimedia> multimediaList;
```

If you do need bidirectional relationship with join table, the mapping will be like this:

```
public class Feature implements Serializable {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="feature")
    private List<Multimedia> multimediaList;
    ...
}

public class Multimedia implements Serializable {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinTable(name = "multimedia_feature",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "multimedia_oid") ,
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "feature_oid"))
    private Feature feature;
    ...
}
```

Or you can totally remove the join table with a bidirectional association by introducing a join column in multimedia table, like feture_oid. So that you can easily map the feature attribute in Multimedia class:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "feature_oid")
private Feature feature;
```

And in the Feature class will be like:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="feature")
private List<Multimedia> multimediaList;
```

Comment: i can't add an attribute in multimedia because this class has others join table with others classes... if i add an attribute for each class, i'll have a lot of "null" values in db... i think it isn't a good practice, right? So, in the first way, what i have to write in the multimedia class?

Comment: @ManyToOne(mapped by multimediaList)
?

Comment: @Marco If you do need to retain the join table and bidirectional bond, then you can use the Multimedia as the owning side and define the join there, and use the mappedBy attribute at the other end which is Feature. I tweaked my answer to demo that.